# SBT console doesn't want to launch in intelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Each time I want to launch SBT console in intelliJ, this message appears :

> ava -Dsbt.log.noformat=true -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
>   -Xmx512M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M -jar /home/nabih/.IntelliJIdea2016.2/system/sbt/sbt-launch.jar.

Another pop-up window displays :

> Unable to start SBT. Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/nabih/anotherTrySBT"): error=2, No such file or directory

I am using ubuntu 16.4.

Answer (score 0):

May be idea can't find java in the project structure.

click on

> File > Project structure > Project > Project SDK

You need to set the javs SDK here

For reference try this link:-

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/configuring-global-project-and-module-sdks.html

Hope that helpes. :)

Comment: thank you for replying, but this is not the solution, I checked the Project SDK and it is recognizing java 1.8.

Comment: If it is saying that 

"Cannot run program "java" (in directory "/home/nabih/anotherTrySBT"): error=2, No such file or directory"

Then it is possible that it can't find the java.